# Email Reminders - Second abandonned cart

Tags: abandoned-cart, email-reminders

I have a question about a specific case with Adobe Commerce reminder email feature.

I created a reminder rule that works well and send email reminder after a certain time the cart is abandoned.
But **what if the customer transforms the cart** into an order and then creates a new cart and abandons it too? Is it possible to trigger again the reminder rule for this customer?

As far as I see in the code and with my test, as a mail has already been sent to the customer it will not trigger it again.

Thanks